# Not able to access shared folders in Virtualbox

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu-10.04, virtualbox, shared-folders

I am running an Ubuntu 10.10 in VirtualBox on my Windows 7

From VirtualBox, I set up a share folder, and I can see it from Ubuntu under `media` folder

```
drwxrwx--- 1 root    vboxsf     0 2011-03-15 16:58 sf_ShareFolderWithVB
```

However, I cannot access it with my current user.

How can I grant the right for myself to access that folder?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add yourself to the vboxsf-group with `sudo adduser <username> vboxsf`.